# validate json against schema in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, schema

*Question:*

Is there a plain or native javascript way to validate a JSON script against a JSON schema?

I have found lots of libraries on Github, but no native/plain solution. Does EcmaScript not have a specification for this? and do none of the browsers (or nodejs) have a way to validate JSON natively?

*Context of Question:*

I have a very complex schema that I developed.
It is supposed to work along with a script that requires that the JSON data passed into it to comply with the schema.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply, no.

There was something called [JSON Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON_Schema), which was an Internet Draft which expired in 2013. Internet Drafts are the first stage to producing an [Internet Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Standard). See more about it at the [official site](http://json-schema.org/), as it seems to potentially still be actively developed, although it is not (to my knowledge) in widespread use.

An example of the schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "Product",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["id", "name", "price"],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "description": "Product identifier"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Name of the product"
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0
    },
    "tags": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "stock": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "warehouse": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "retail": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will validate this example JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Foo",
  "price": 123,
  "tags": [
    "Bar",
    "Eek"
  ],
  "stock": {
    "warehouse": 300,
    "retail": 20
  }
}
```

Comment: So, if I wanted to validate JSON what should I do?

Comment: Use an external library. I'll update with some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, my biggest issue was relying on libraries that may not be reliable

Comment: what about for browsers (client-side)?

Comment: You can use [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for browser validation. It is a powerful and flexible solution. But you need to convert JSON to JS object first.

Comment: `As they all (more or less) do the same thing and have very similar syntaxes, performance should be of the biggest concern.` This is pretty opinionated and is simply not good advice in a lot of cases. In many cases, the performance affect of your JSON validator is likely to be completely negligible, in which case any time spent comparing performance is completely wasted

Comment: @ICW you are more than right - answer edited

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be at least one pure JS solution now (https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema) available via npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema). I am not a contributor, although I appreciate their work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [{Edictor}](https://github.com/nitipit/edictor)
I've just created a solution from other perspective in 2023.

The thing is to define schema for Javascript Object and validate the assigned data. Then we can retrieve native object or JSON.

It can deal with any kind of data and support RegEx through validation APIs.

The project's here [https://nitipit.github.io/edictor/](https://github.com/nitipit/edictor)

For example, you can create schema for [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json) like this..

```js
/** ES Module */
import { Model, defineField } from 'edictor';

/** define class `Package` & `People` to ba a schema */
class Package extends Model {};
class People extends Model {};

/** Define reusable `defineField()` as `urlDef`
 * - Data must be string instance.
 * - Validate url by `apply()` which expect function to throw error
 *   if data is not valid.
 */
const urlDef = defineField()
    .instance('string')
    .apply((value) => { new URL(value) })

/** Define `People` model structure */
People.define({
    name: defineField({required: true})
        .instance('string'),
    email: defineField()
        .instance('string')
        .regexp(/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/),
    url: urlDef
})

/** Define `Package` model structure */
Package.define({
    name: defineField({required: true})
        .instance('string')
        .assert((value) => { return value.length <= 214 },
            "The name must be less than or equal to 214 characters"),
    version: /** https://ihateregex.io/expr/semver/ */
        defineField({required: true})
        .instance('string')
        .regexp(/^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$/),
    homepage: urlDef,
    author: /** Nesting field */
        defineField()
        .model(People),
    contributors: /** Nesting array field
        defineField({initial: []})
        .arrayOf(People)
})
```