# Javascript - Validate a Json with a schema

Tags: javascript, json, validation, schema

I want to validate a json with a custom schema.
What is the command to do this in javascript?

I search for something like:

```
schemaValidator.validate(json, schema)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936442/validate-json-against-schema-in-javascript

Comment: This may be of some use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema

Comment: Possible duplicate of [validate json against schema in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936442/validate-json-against-schema-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it only possible with a library? Isn't there a command to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a library to do schema validation, even integrated with express: 
[schema-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/schema-validator)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use a software that use javascript. Install a library is maybe a little complicate. Is there a command to to this?